# lookup mongodb not working as e

Tags: mongodb

Order and riders this collections I have created with data
riders

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5a55b5fb99391a1694fa4541",
    "name": "rider4",
    "email": "rider4@gmail.com",
    "mob": "3d4",
    "city": "Sotland",
    "address": "UK",
    "postcode": "411041",
    "password": "123456",
    "__v": 0,
    "device_token": "d12223",
    "status": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a55b5e399391a1694fa453f",
    "name": "rider2",
    "email": "rider2@gmail.com",
    "mob": "34",
    "city": "Sotland",
    "address": "UK",
    "postcode": "411041",
    "password": "123456",
    "__v": 0,
    "device_token": "12223",
    "status": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a55b5a299391a1694fa453a",
    "name": "rider3",
    "email": "rider3@gmail.com",
    "mob": "2",
    "city": "Sotland",
    "address": "UK",
    "postcode": "411041",
    "password": "123456",
    "__v": 0,
    "device_token": "123",
    "status": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a5453a76b7be60004bc8e67",
    "name": "rider1",
    "email": "rider1@gmail.com",
    "mob": "62345674d890",
    "city": "Sotland",
    "address": "UK",
    "postcode": "411041",
    "password": "123456",
    "__v": 0,
    "device_token": "123",
    "status": false
  }
]
```

Order collections has:

```
    {
        "_id": "5a599b750cdf310004334087",
        "orderNumber": "1",
        "riderId": "5a55b5e399391a1694fa453f"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a599b600cdf310004334086",
        "orderNumber": "1",
        "riderId": "5a55b5a299391a1694fa453a"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a599b380cdf310004334085",
        "orderNumber": "1",
        "riderId": "5a5453a76b7be60004bc8e67"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a599b0c0cdf310004334084",
        "orderNumber": "1",
        "riderId": "5a55b5fb99391a1694fa4541"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a599af30cdf310004334083",
        "orderNumber": "1",
        "riderId": "5a55b5fb99391a1694fa4541"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a599ad90cdf310004334082",
        "orderNumber": "1",
        "riderId": "5a55b5e399391a1694fa453f"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a599ac00cdf310004334081",
        "orderNumber": "1",
        "riderId": "5a55b5a299391a1694fa453a"
    },
```

I am running these queries:

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
              {$match:{'order_created':"1/13/18" }},
               {$lookup:{"from":"rider","localField":"riderId", 
"foreignField":"RID","as":"rider"}}])
```

It shows output

```
rider : 0
```

Comment: Your data has no `order_created` field, so none of your documents match.

Comment: 1. order doesn't have `order_created` 2. rider doesn't have `RID`